# Schemes as set valued functors on the category of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{Sch}$ be the category of schemes.
Let $\mathcal{Aff}$ be the category of affine schemes.
Let $\mathcal{Sets}$ be the category of sets.
Let $X$ be a scheme.
Let $h_X\colon \mathcal{Sch}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{Sets}$ be the functor defined by $h_X(T) = Hom(T, X)$.
By Yoneda lemma, $h_X \cong h_Y$ if and only if $X \cong Y$.

Let $g_X\colon \mathcal{Aff}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{Sets}$ be the restriction of $h_X$.
Then $g_X \cong g_Y$ if and only if $X \cong Y$?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  This is a consequence of the Yoneda Lemma result that you cite, *together with* the fact that any scheme has an open cover by affine schemes, and that morphisms of schemes can be constructed by working locally and then gluing.

Comment: Let $\psi\colon g_X \rightarrow g_Y$ be a natural transformation.
Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be an affine open cover of $X$.
Let $\tau_i\colon U_i \rightarrow X$ be the canonical morphism.
Let $f_i = \psi_{U_i}(\tau_i) \colon U_i \rightarrow Y$.
It is easy to see that $f_i = f_j$ on $U_i \cap U_j$.
Hence there exists a unique morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f|U_i = f_i$.
Let $S$ be an affine scheme, $h\colon S \rightarrow X$ a morphism.
I'm wondering how to show $fh = \psi_S(h)$.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Dear Makoto, You will want to choose an open affine cover of $S$ compatible with your open affine cover of $X$ (i.e. so that $f$ applied to each member of the first lies in a member of the second).  Then you should be able to finish.  Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Let $\psi\colon g_X \rightarrow g_Y$ be a natural transformation.
We construct a morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ inducing $\psi$ as follows.

Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be an affine open cover of $X$.
Let $\tau_i\colon U_i \rightarrow X$ be the canonical morphism.
Let $f_i = \psi_{U_i}(\tau_i) \colon U_i \rightarrow Y$.
We get the following commutative diagram.

$$\begin{matrix}
g_X(U_i)&\stackrel{\psi_{U_i}}{\rightarrow}&g_Y(U_i)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
g_X(U_i\cap U_j)&\stackrel{\psi_{U_i\cap U_j}}{\rightarrow}&g_Y(U_i\cap U_j)
\end{matrix}
$$

By the above diagram, $f_i = f_j$ on $U_i \cap U_j$.
Hence there exists a unique morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f|U_i = f_i$.

Let $S$ be an affine scheme, $h\colon S \rightarrow X$ a morphism.
We will show $fh = \psi_S(h)$.
Let $x \in S$. There exists $i \in I$ such that $h(x) \in U_i$.
Since $h$ is continuous, there exists an affine open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that $h(V_x) \subset U_i$.
Hence there exists an affine open cover $(V_j)_{j\in J}$ with the following property.
For each $j \in J$, there exists $i \in I$ such that $h(V_j) \subset U_i$.
Hence there exists a map $\phi\colon J \rightarrow I$ such that $h(V_j) \subset U_{\phi(j)}$ for each $j \in J$. Let $h'_j\colon V_j \rightarrow U_{\phi(j)}$ be the morphism induced by $h$.
Let $h_j = \tau_{\phi(j)} h'_j \colon V_j \rightarrow X$.

$$\begin{matrix}
g_X(U_{\phi(j)})&\stackrel{\psi_{U_{\phi(j)}}}{\rightarrow}&g_Y(U_{\phi(j)})\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
g_X(V_j)&\stackrel{\psi_{V_j}}{\rightarrow}&g_Y(V_j)
\end{matrix}
$$

By the above commutative diagram, $\psi_{V_j}(h_j) = fh_j$.

$$\begin{matrix}
g_X(S)&\stackrel{\psi_S}{\rightarrow}&g_Y(S)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
g_X(V_j)&\stackrel{\psi_{V_j}}{\rightarrow}&g_Y(V_j)
\end{matrix}
$$

By the above commutative diagram, $\psi_S(h)|V_j = fh|V_j$ for each $j \in J$.
Hence $\psi_S(h) = fh$.
Therefore $f$ induces $\psi$.

Suppose $\psi\colon g_X \rightarrow g_Y$ is a natural equivalence.
Then, by the above argument, there exists a morphism $f'\colon Y \rightarrow X$ inducing $\psi^{-1}$.
Since $f'f$ induces the identity on $h_X$, $f'f = id_X$.
Similarly $ff' = id_Y$.
Hence $f$ is an isomorphism.